# kaa send notification from client to server

Tags: kaa

I understand kaa server can send message to kaa node, either individually or to all nodes.

However, I am curious to know if a kaa node can send message back to kaa server.

Thanks And Regards,
Rupak Banerjee.

Answer (score 0):

KAA provides 2 way communication,

1. Notification :: When KAA Server sends message or request to KAA Endpoint(End Device).
2. Log Push :: When KAA Endpoint responds to Notification request or KAA Endpoint can send message to Server as Traps.